# Rotate axis TEXT labels in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to rotate the y axis label to be horizontal instead of vertical, but every post I see only talks about rotating the tick marks on the y axis. For example, running `ggplot(mpg, aes(fl)) + geom_bar() + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))` generates the following plot:

[image]

I want "count" to be horizontal instead of vertical. I have tried `las` and `theme()`, but none of these have rotated the y axis TEXT label. Is this possible to do in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very possible to do what you're looking to do.  The axis *title* is different than the *text* (the labels of the tick marks on the axis).  Consequently, the `theme()` element you want to address is `axis.title.y`.  As with the axis text, you address using `element_text()` and supply an angle.  In this case, the angle is set to 90 degrees by default, so you want to rotate back to `angle=0`.  Importantly, you will want to adjust the vertical alignment too, which is set to be aligned at the top by default.  To put the title in the middle of the axis, you need a vertical alignment of 0.5.

```
p <- your plot code
p + theme(axis.title.y=element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.5))
```

[image]